# What is the precise meaning of the word ‘beget’ in this text

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, disambiguation

I know the meaning of the verb ‘beget’: reproduce, cause, bring about,father, give rise to, …

It is just that in this context I cannot get what is meant by it. Does it mean giving rise to ‘technocratic’ solutions? So what is meant by that?

> Starting somewhat as a whisper, a discourse has steadily grown that
> problems of environmental sustainability and resilience are less the
> product of willful blindness on the part of political and economic
> elites, than a reflection of nature’s hidden, and consequently
> unrevealed, value; a procedural problem **begetting** technocratic
> solutions. To this end, concepts and frameworks have been invented that have steadily shaped and harmonised models of evidence gathering about the natural world across whole fields of science and practice, enabling scientists not only to quantify, measure and monitor nature’s many and diverse benefits for people, but crucially, to systematically value these benefits in the context of the decision-making processes of government, business and civil society. These practices define what is understood by many in environmental research as the ‘valuation of nature’ and are practices tethered strongly to both the concept of ecosystem services and to the elaboration and use of economics with respect to environmental concerns. It is thus helpful to read this book in conjunction with some basic appreciation of the history of this discourse, since it guides some of the background logic of the content. (Source: ٰValuing Nature: The Roots of Transformation. By Robert Fish, Holly McKelvey)

Comment: I'm wondering if it is not a typo/misunderstanding for "be**s**etting"

Comment: @Greybeard Very good point. That makes much more sense, actually. I wonder what a translator is supposed to do in such cases!

Comment: _I wonder what a translator is supposed to do in such cases_ ... One can only try to ascertain what the author intended, perhaps via the publishers. Obviously not an ELU question until the intended text is verified.

Comment: The entire text is pretentious twaddle. But it looks to me like ***begetting*** there should have been ***besetting*** anyway.

Comment: It is unclear in your question why you do not equate "begetting" to "giving rise to". This seems a simple understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this context it means "leads to"

I hope this helps. Please feel free to reach out in case of any further discussion required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).